# Detecting the failure of LED

Tags: led, relay

I am using a 12V LED for blinking purpose. Whenever it gets a signal from source(indicating the emission of rays), it blinks. The signal voltage out of the source is 5V. The supply to the source is 24V. I am using a relay in between the source and the LED.

Whenever the source is triggered, the signal from the source triggers the relay and in turn LED blinks.The challenge i am facing right now is:
If the LED fails, the source should not emit the rays itself. Basically it should check whether the led is working or not and then signal should come out from the source. If the led is not working even though the source is triggered, the source should not emit the rays. How can i achieve it? Is it possible with a relay or a led with feedback circuit or any other? Thanks in advance.

Comment: now we've got three voltages in your question: 12V, 5V and 24V, and absolutely no idea how everything is connected. Your question remains unclear; you *must* draw a schematic that explains your setup.

Comment: The relay is going to fail LONG before the LED does. However, that aside, you can measure and detect the LED current with a suitable circuit / comparator and use that to disable the source. Measuring the LED when it is turned off is more problematic though.

Comment: Rays????  What?  Signal from the source???  What kind of signal?  What is this source with rays, signals, and voltages??  You got some 'splain' to do.

Comment: What do you mean by 'blinks'?

Comment: I am guessing OP is saying that the LED is some kind of warning light that the device is going to emit (possibly harmful) rays, perhaps something like an x-ray machine. If that warning light fails to light, then for safety reasons the machine must not emit any rays. Vignesh, is this correct?

Comment: You are right Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "12 V LED" is likely an LED in series with a resistor. You'll need to get access to the intermediate node between the LED and the resistor. Or else get rid of your "12 V LED" and use a separate LED and resistor of your choosing.

Now, what you'll do is apply voltage to the LED-resistor combo first. And monitor the voltage at the intermediate node with a couple of comparators. If that voltage is less than maybe 1 V, it means the LED has failed short. If the voltage is greater than 2 or 3 V (depending on the LED color) it means the LED has failed open. Two comparators can check these two conditions. If you use open-drain output comparators, you can make a wired-AND connection at their outputs, and connect this to your control circuit. Only if both comparators give the expected output, you turn on your ray gun.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3d7EB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The common name for this circuit is a *window comparator*.

None of this will work if the failure mode of the LED is, for example, somebody spilled paint on it.

Answer (score 1):

The surest way to detect an LED's operation is an optodetector.   Ideally, have a bit of a lightpipe between the LED and the visual display so room lighting doesn't spoof the optodetector.

It's better to *detect what is actually occurring* rather than guess what *should* be occurring from secondary indicators.  Recall the Three Mile Island accident, caused by an indicator showing a *pilot-operated valve* was closed; it actually showed *power was cut off* to the pilot; it did not indicate actual position of *pilot* let alone the valve proper.   You are always best detecting the *actual* state-of-affairs.

Nothing requires the optodetector be on the same system that drives the LED.  So the machine that generates rays could look at the optodetector to affirm the LED is actually on.